# using scrapy to extract multiple separate entries from the same table

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to python and web scraping in general and I'm trying to use scrapy to extract data from a website.  What I'm having trouble is that the data I need is all in the same table and many of its elements have the same tags.  The HTML looks like this:

```html
<table cellpadding="10"><tr><td valign="top">
</td><td><br>
<br><br><big><b>1-555-555-1111</b></big>
<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;LAST, FIRST MIDDLE
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Residence address:</b> 1234 street rd ,  , CITY,   12345
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sex: M
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Race: Black, not Hispanic
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Birth date: 16 January 1968
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Voter ID number: 111111111
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Visit the <a href="https://webpage.html">Detail Page of LAST FIRST MIDDLE</a>
<br><br><big><b>1-555-555-1112</b></big>
<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;BLAST, BFIRST BM.
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Residence address:</b> 1234   ANOTHER ST ,  #2-213, CITY,   12345
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sex: F
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Race: White, not Hispanic
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Birth date: 18 December 1933
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Voter ID number: 111111112
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Visit the <a href="https://webpage.html">Detail Page of LAST FIRST MIDDLE</a>'
<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;BBLAST, BBFIRST BBM.
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Mailing address:</b> PO BOX 1323, CITY, ST 12345
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Residence address:</b> 1234   ANOTHER ST ,  #2-213, CITY, ST  12345
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sex: F
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Race: White, not Hispanic
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Birth date: 18 December 1933
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Voter ID number: 111111113
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Visit the <a href="https://webpage.html">Detail Page of LAST FIRST MIDDLE</a>'
```

I need to extract the data and be able to output it to a .csv file.  I need to have this data in a CSV with each person in their own row.  I'm having trouble because I don't know how to extract it and keep it in order due to how some of the entries have more than one person on the same phone number and in those entries the phone number is not printed for each individual, just one time. The individuals attached to that number are both listed under that single entry.  Also, sometimes there is a mailing address field and a residential address field.

I just need to make sure that when the data is extracted, the phone number field is properly populated for individuals who share a number with another individual and I need to make sure there is an empty field for the mailing address for the entries that don't have a separate address there.

When I have attempted to pull anything myself I can extract the data but it isn't properly keeping the entries with the correct person because as soon as it hits an entry with more than one person in the phone numbers section it makes those names all off by one phone number.  Currently, I have the following code written just to try and extract the number and DOB:

```
import scrapy
class NumspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'numspider'
    allowed_domains = ['scraped.site']
    start_urls = ['https://scraped.site']
    def parse(self, response):
        numbers = response.xpath('//td[2]/big/b/text()').extract()
        dob = response.xpath(".//td[2]/following::text()[contains(., 'Birth date')]").extract()
    yield {'Number': numbers, 'DOB': dob}
```

Also this unfortunately has the added problem of pulling things I don't want as well such as my birthdays looking like `u'\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Birth date: 16 January 1968\n` and my numbers looking like this `u'1-555-555-1111'`. When I get this info to my final CSV I want it to read `16 January 1968` and `16 January 1968`

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want as well such as my birthdays looking like u'\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Birth date: 16 January 1968\n and my numbers looking like this u'1-555-555-1111'. When I get this info to my final CSV I want it to read 16 January 1968 and 16 January 1968

That part is easy to solve: `dob = map(lambda x: x.strip(), dob)` since `\xa0` is considered "whitespace" and thus is stripped off with its `\n` friend. You can similarly kill the `Birth date:`: `map(lambda x: re.sub(r'Birth date:\s*', '', x.strip()), dob)`

However, for the larger answer to your question, I wanted to offer for your consideration that what you have isn't actually an HTML problem, it's that a text format is buried in HTML. That situation feels like the same as if they had wrapped all that text in `<pre>`: there isn't a selector that is going to "reach into" the `<pre>`.

However, since it is a line oriented format, you can use some well placed splits to chop them up into master detail records based on the indentation and the trailing text of a detail record. I'm actually pretty disappointed that `string(//td[2])` didn't preserve the `<br><br>` split between the detail records, but *c'est la vie*.

```
def parse(self, response):
    the_text = response.xpath("string(//td[2])").extract_first().replace("\xa0", " ").lstrip()
    # kill the leading "\n" entry and split on flush phone numbers
    records = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, re.split(r'(?m)^([0-9-]+)$', the_text)))
    for i in range(0, len(records), 2):
        phone = records[i]
        rest = records[i+1]
        details = re.split(r'(?m)^\s+Visit the Detail Page.*$', rest)
        for det in details:
            print('detail[ {} ] := {}'.format(phone, det))
            # etc etc
```